# BeautifulSoup Парсер элементов

Tags: python, парсер

Подскажите пожалуйста, как спарсить `div id`элемента `c15597187`

```
<div id="c15597187" class="l_class">

<a class="ref_goods_n_p j-open-full-product-card" href="/catalog/15597187/detail.aspx?targetUrl=GP" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/ImageObject">
```

или `href="/catalog/15597187/detail.aspx?targetUrl=GP"`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.request
import textwrap
import csv


def cprint(text, color='def'):
    str = ''
    fc = '\033['
    colors = {'def': '0m',
              'red': '91m',
              'under': '04m',
              'green': '32m',
              'blue': '94m',
              'cyan': '96m',
              'yellow': '93m',
              'magenta': '95m',
              'grey': '90m'
              }
    if color not in colors:
        print(str + fc + colors['def'] + text)
    else:
        if color == 'under':
            print(str + fc + colors['under'] + text)
        else:
            print(str + fc + colors[color] + text)
def parser(link):
    req = urllib.request.urlopen(link)
    html = req.read()

    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
    news = soup.find_all('div', class_='dtlist-inner-brand')

    for item in news:
        title = item.find('div', class_='dtlist-inner-brand-name').get_text(strip=True)
        price = item.find('div', class_='j-cataloger-price').get_text(strip=True)
        # #href = item.find('a', {'class': 'ref_goods_n_p'}).get('href')
        # #link = item.find('a', class_='ref_goods_n_p j-open-full-product-card').get('href')
        # #href = soup.find_all('a', class_='ref_goods_n_p j-open-full-product-card')[0]
        # href = item.find("div", {"id": "l_class"})
        # print(href)
        href = item.findAll("div", {"id": "c15597187"})

        print(title, end=" = ")
        print("\033[4m\033[37m\033[40m{}\033[0m".format(price))
        print(href)


x = "https://www.wildberries.ru/catalog/knigi-i-kantstovary/kantstovary/bumazhnaya-produktsiya"
b = 1
for i in range(1):
    parser(x)
    b += 1
    x = "https://www.wildberries.ru/catalog/knigi-i-kantstovary/kantstovary/bumazhnaya-produktsiya" + "?page=" + str(b)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

C div

```
soup.find("div", {"id": "c15597187"})
```

Или без

```
soup.find(id="c15597187")
```

Что бы найти все

```
soup.findAll("div", {"id": "c15597187"}):
```

найти несколько id

```
soup.findAll("div", {"id": ["c15597187","anotherID"]})
```

Вы также можете выбрать конкреытный блок

Имена с точкой значит класс .someclass

Без точки тег div

Если в имени есть пробел то его можно заменить точкой .some.class

id если я не ошибаюсь выберается решеткой #someid

```
soup.select(".ufoot > div > .post_rating > span")
```

Получить значение из href

```
soup["href"]
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, на странице вывод товаров c15597187 у каждого свой, пробовал как вы советуете не получается, добавил в сообщение полный код

Comment: На той же строке есть l_class  |  soup.findAll("div", {"class": "l_class"})

Comment: Вот так удалось решить id_e = item.find(attrs={'class': 'l_class'})['id'] проблемма еще была в том что news = soup.find_all('div', class_='dtlist-inner-brand') div класс брал на уровень ниже скорее всего все ваши варианты верны, спасибо!